# Python comparing strings to their equivalent integers effeciently

Tags: python

What's the most efficient way to compare two python values both of which are probably strings, but might be integers.  So far I'm using str(x)==str(y) but that feels inefficient and (more importantly) ugly:

```
>>> a = 1.0
>>> b = 1
>>> c = '1'
>>> a == b
True
>>> b == c
False  # here I wanted this to be true
>>> str(b)==str(c)
True   # true, as desired
```

My actual objects are dictionary values retrieved with get(), and most of them are strings.

Comment: what do you want `str(a) == str(b)` to be? As it is, it's `False`, so you're not consistent with the integer comparison. What about `str(c) == str(a)`?

Comment: it should be noted: premature optimization is the root of all evil.  It's highly unlikely that this is the bottleneck in your program

Comment: I actually wanted all of these to be equivalent: 1, 1.0, '1', '1.0', which as @agf notes is not achieved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test it out.  I like using `%timeit` in `ipython`:

```
In [1]: %timeit str("1") == str(1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 702 ns per loop

In [2]: %timeit "1" == str(1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 412 ns per loop

In [3]: %timeit int("1") == 1
1000000 loops, best of 3: 906 ns per loop
```

Apart from that, though, if you truly don't know what the input type is, there isn't much you can do about it, unless you want to make assumptions about the input data. For example, if you assume that *most* of the inputs are equal (same type, same value), you could do something like:

```
if a == b or str(a) == str(b):
    ... they are equal ...
```

Which *would* be faster if they are normally the same type and normally equal... But it will be slower if they aren't normally the same type, or aren't normally equal.

However, are you sure you can't cast everything to a str/int when they enter your code?

Comment: Explicitly: Yes, this is pretty efficient. Don't prematurely optimize.

Comment: If almost all of them are strings, you should be using `try` / `except` not a double compare. This is especially true on Python 3 where more mismatched comparisons will raise `TypeError`.

Comment: Why is that, @agf? Because of the couple extra opcodes for the `or`? Also, how could it be coaxed into raising a type error? Even in py3, `"a" == 3` returns `False`, no type error…

Comment: Since they are mostly string don't you want to compare `str("1") == str("1")` with `"1" == "1"` ? (in my test calling str makes it 5 times slower)

Comment: @Mihai: are you referencing my second example? If so, this works because the right hand side of the `or` is not evaluated if the left hand side is true… So the `str(a) == str(b)` is only executed if `a != b`.

Comment: yes, but he never said that most of them are equal, just that most are strings

Comment: Yes, he did. Which is why I prefaced that example with “… unless you … make assumptions about the input data. … if you assume that most of the inputs are equal (same type, same value) …”.

Answer (score 1):

```
wim@wim-acer:~/sandpit$ python -mtimeit "str('69') == str(69)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.28 usec per loop
wim@wim-acer:~/sandpit$ python -mtimeit "int('69') == int(69)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.5 usec per loop
wim@wim-acer:~/sandpit$ python -mtimeit "str('32767') == str(32767)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.317 usec per loop
wim@wim-acer:~/sandpit$ python -mtimeit "int('32767') == int(32767)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.492 usec per loop
```

Conclusion: Probably how you're already doing it is plenty fast enough.  Optimise the slowest parts of your program, *after* everything is working.